# Can [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys cause a buffer overrun?

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

I have the following function in my code:

```
NSMutableDictionary* productDictionary =
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:productIdentifier, @"Product ID", @(difficulty), @"Difficulty", nil];
```

If productIdentifier is nil, is it possible that this is cause a buffer overrun and write data beyond its allocated bounds?

Thanks for you help,
- Rich

Answer (score 1):

No, if it's `nil` you will simply get an empty dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments in the variable argument list are only *read*. You might get a "bad access" hardware exception when you forgot to set a terminating `nil`.

I would guess, if the first parameter *firstObject* is `nil`, you safely get an empty dictionary.